# Pulling files from real devices in appium iOS

Tags: python, ios, appium

Im having a difficult time trying to pull files and folders in one of my automated tests using appium. We use real devices for testing and I would like to use `driver.pull_file()` to accomplish this task. The files I want exist in the On My iPad folder, and I cannot figure out how to get the file path of the actual file in that location on the device.

Does anyone know where exactly I can find the right path? or what it would look like?

Answer (score 0):

[How to](https://osxdaily.com/2021/10/19/get-file-paths-iphone-ipad-files-app/) get the file path of a file on iOS.